# Address State and Country not visible on the records

Tags: account, fields, ui, address, country-and-state

Dear friends I have an interesting problem.
The address fields are not correct visible on the records.
On the account page I see all address fields, but on the Address record and Service Territory I cannot see the State and Country fields.
BUT, on the other sandbox I have not this problem.

All settings are the same on the both sandboxes.
[image: Address on the account record]

[image: The same address on the Address object]

Comment: Are your sandboxes the same version? A number of items related to Address and State/Country was changed in Summer 22.

Comment: Yes. The versions are the same. 
The Summer update was installed.
" A number of items related to Address and State/Country was changed in Summer 22" - please clarify this moment. What should I check?

Comment: If both sandboxes are Summer '22, then the release is not the issue.